# Warning: scandir(/game/c_images/album1584/): failed to open dir: not implemented in

Tags: php, array

Estou tendo esses Warning ao executar esse código em meu localhost alguem poderia me dar alguma solução?

Obrigado ^^

```
<?php
    $target = "http://localhost:8080/game/c_images/album1584/";
    $weeds = array('.', '..');
    $sucess = "";

    $directories = array_diff(scandir($target), $weeds);
    if (is_dir($target)) { 
    foreach($directories as $value)
    {
        $gifkill            = str_replace('.gif', '', $value);
        $gif2kill           = str_replace('.GIF', '', $gifkill);
        $uppercasewords     = ucwords($gif2kill);

        if(is_file($target.$value))
        {
            echo "INSERT INTO `holly`.`badge_definitions` (`code`, `required_right`) VALUES ('".$uppercasewords."', '');<br />";
            $sucess = true;
    }
    if($sucess == false){
        echo "Não foi possível executar";
    }else{
     echo "Show!!";
  }
}
}else{
    echo "nao deu";
}?>
```

```php
Warning: scandir(http://localhost:8080/game/c_images/album1584/): failed to open dir: not implemented in C:\xampp\htdocs\game\c_images\album1584\badgedef.php on line 13

Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\game\c_images\album1584\badgedef.php on line 13

Warning: array_diff(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\game\c_images\album1584\badgedef.php on line 13
```

Comment: Você está tentando acessar um diretório a partir de uma URL?

Comment: mesmo colocando "C:\xampp\htdocs\game\c_images\album1584" não resolve

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Caio!
Você está tentando manipular arquivos, certo? O erro é causado pelo motivo de você acessar o arquivo diretamente pela url, o que poderia ser feito se acessado utilizando diretamente as pastas do projeto.
O comando "require" poderia ajudar.
Exemplo:
 $target = require('caminhodoarquivo')

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando checar se $target é uma pasta, porém você definiu como um link.
No caso, $target deve ser $target = "./game/c_images/album1584/"; caso a pasta game esteja na mesma pasta do seu documento php.